# Cleanest way of returning different structures for the same request

Tags: json, rest, api-design

I want to implement a rest service that takes in an object and returns if the object is eligible to be processed with certain parameters. The problem is that **depending on whether the object is eligible or not the structure of the response is very different**. As an example in case the object should be processed it is associated with a processing type and priority. When it is not eligible the reason for this is returned. Which is the **cleanest way of returning different structures for the same request**. There are three options I could think of but feel free to add additional options.

Option A:
Return data as envelope containing with field that is structured

```
{
    "eligible": bool,
    "data": {
        // Data depending on whether elbile or not
    }
}
```

Option B:
Use different HTTP status code and structure json accordingly. This is somehow unclean, since it is not really an error in the request but a valid response.

Option C:
Use different fields for the data send in case of eligible or not and let one field be null.

```
{
    "eligible": bool,
    "dataEligible": {
        "processingType": "",
        "priority": 0
    }
    "dataNonEligible": {
        "reason": "",
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would be good use-case for [422 Status Code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2). It is not official ISO yet, but a lot companies (i.e. Twitter) is using it.

Basically it is what happens for you - the resource could not be processed, altough server understand the request and it is correct syntax.

---

The option C also look reasonable, therefore use the one which is the most appropriate for your needs. I would not recommend A, as different format for same request is huge problem for consumers with static-typed languages (i.e. Java)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I considered 422 as well correct me if I am wrong. but doesn't it imply that the send request has semantic errors?

Comment: No, 422 is without any errors, but still the server cannot process it for some reason unknown to client